# AWS WebSocket API with IAM authorizations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, api-gateway

I am trying to set up IAM authorizations for a WebSocket API.

I use Cognito Identity Pool to get credentials with a custom role, and I can attach my policy to that role.

The problem is that I'm only able to allow or deny invoking $connect route, and therefore, the whole API. Every other statement is ignored.

That's not what's said in the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-control-access-iam.html) (you can control each resource by itself).

Is there something missing ?

Comment: Is your idea to use authorization for every route, not only `$connect`?
If you go to the `$connect` route's _Route Request_, it clearly states:
_"Configure how clients will be authorized to access this WebSocket API. Only the $connect route contains auth settings. After the WebSocket connection is established, each message sent from the client will use the same authorization strategy."_